# Get index of items in one column of lists from another column of lists

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns

```
column_1                column_2
["apple","orange"]      ["orange", "apple"]
["banana"]              ["apple"]
```

I want a result column which will tell what index is the item in `column_2` is present in `column_1`. Return -1 if not present.
Ex: output would be

```
output_column
[1,0]
[-1]
```

Comment: How large are your sublists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sublists are small:

```
df['output_column'] = df.apply(lambda x:[x.column_1.index(item) if item in x.column_1 else -1 for item in x.column_2],axis=1)
```

And if your sublists are large:

```
df['output_column'] = df.apply(lambda x:[dict((value,idx) for idx,value in enumerate(x.column_1)).get(item,-1) for item in x.column_2],axis=1)
```

output:

```
          column_1         column_2 output_column
0  [apple, orange]  [orange, apple]        [1, 0]
1         [banana]          [apple]          [-1]
```